# I'm facing problem in choosing backend based on query params using lua in haproxy

Tags: lua, haproxy

```
local function choose_backend(applet)
    local queryParam = applet.qs
    core.Info("params"..queryParam)
    if string.match(queryParam,"value1") then
        return "backend1"
    else
        return "backend2"
    end
end

core.register_service("choose_backend","http",choose_backend)
```

Also core.register_service not working in choosing backend dynamically

=================================================================================================

I have used core.register_fetches for choosing backend but getting issue in fetching query params using txn object.

```
core.register_fetches("choose_backend", function(txn)
    if string.match(querparam,"value1") then
        return "backend1"
    else
        return "backend2"
    end  
end)
```

Comment: What is exactly the issue?

Comment: I need suggestion in fetching query params using txn object in lua.